# Prove that when $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$ doesn't always mean that $A \subseteq B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

How to prove, when $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$ doesn't "always" mean that $$A \subseteq B$$

when $ f\colon X \to Y $ is **total** function (not partial)

Comment: Note that in each of the answers below, we are dealing with functions that are not one-to-one. It's a good exercise to show that a function $f:X\to Y$ is one-to-one *if and only if* $f(A)\subseteq f(B)$ always means $A\subseteq B$ for $A,B\subseteq X.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+, x\mapsto x^2$
And then see
$$f([0, 2]) = f([-2, 0])$$

Answer (score 7):

take $f$ to be a real valued constant function defined on the set of all real numbers, ie $f(x) = 1$ for all real $x$. then the relation $f(A) \subset f(B)$ is always satisfied

Answer (score 2):

To prove that an implication isn't true, i.e., that it doesn't always hold, we need only exhibit a counterexample (or example showing when the implication is false).

Consider the function $f(x) = x^2$, $A = \mathbb R,\; B= \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$.

$f(A) = f(B),$ but $A \not\subseteq B$.

Comment: i thought about this too, but the problem is in the defination of the total function which says that $\forall x \in X$, $\exists$ exactly one $y \in Y$, in your example $ f(2) = f(-2) = 4 $ \|f^(-1)(4)\| > 1$

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding [total function vs. partial function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_function#Total_function). A total function is a function: it maps every $x$ in the domain to some $y$ in the codomain. This does not require that the function be one-to-one, which is what you are implying.

Comment: Good points. +)

Answer (score 1):

Take $X=\{1,2\}$, $Y=\{y\}$ and $f(1)=f(2)=y$ (no ambiguity). Then $f(\{1\})=f(\{2\})=Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \left\{0\right\}$, and any two disjoint stes in $\mathbb{R}$.  For example, consider $I=\left[0,1\right]$ and $J=\left[-1,0\right)$.  Clearly $I\cap J=\emptyset$ and $f(I)=\left\{0\right\}\subseteq f(J)=\left\{0\right\}$.  Hence, $f$, $I$, and $J$ are a counterexample for the given proof.